# how to match two date value for print string in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am getting date from data base table .I get duedate from database till here all is proper
Now i have to compare this duedate with current date if current date is more or equal then duedate which is coming from database then i wany to print string on cell as 'Due'

i try lot but my problem is that the string value showing some ware and they not showing some ware
what is the mistack in my code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString* duedate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:taskobject.DueDate];


    NSDate *currentdate;
    currentdate=[NSDate date];
    //NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString* duedate1 = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentdate];

    if ([currentdate compare:taskobject.DueDate]!=NSOrderedDescending) {
        DateLable.text=@"Due";
        DateLable.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }
    else{
        DateLable.text=duedate;
        DateLable.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSComparisonResult result = [currentdate compare: duedate];
if( result == NSOrderedDescending || result==NSOrderedSame) {
    // true when the dates are the same or the currentdate is later
} else {
   // true when the currentdate is earlier
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this comparesa two dates and tells if there is the difference of 24 hrs in two dates, 
timeIntervalSinceDate:lastLoadDate sends the seconds difference.

```
double interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:lastLoadDate];
    if (interval > 86400 || interval < -86400 ) {
        return YES;   
    }
    else
    {
        enableButtons = YES;
        return NO;

    }
```

in your case it will be

```
double interval = [dueDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];

if (interva >=0)
{   
    DateLable.text=@"Due";
    DateLable.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
}
else
{
    DateLable.text=duedate;
    DateLable.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: This kind of comparison falls over if there is a change in daylight savings etc. (i.e. that day is *not* 86400 seconds long). Better look into `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` to calculate the difference between two dates.